# Excel file uploading works in Chrome, not working in IE 8. Error: 'could not find the part of the path'

Tags: c#, excel, security, internet-explorer, file-upload

May be there are many helpful links about **could not find the part of the path** error in internet, but I get that error in only **IE**. Uploading works fine in **Chrome**.  This issue is on server only. On local they also work fine. My related code is:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/_Uploads/Temp"), uploadedFile.FileName);
```

I am sure **_Uploads** and **Temp** folders are exist. Because I uploaded files with Chrome. I gave full access to **_Uploads** folder too on server. I found a link about IE security in this [link](http://support.genopro.com/Topic25125.aspx), but there is not **My Computer** tab in my settings.

Who had same issue? How can fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

As always `IE` took my all day and I solved that issue. In `IE8` there is a security option that does not allow to get path of uploaded file. We need to to set it `disabled`. Here is:

**IE 8 -> Internet options -> Security -> Local Internet -> Custom Level -> Include local directory path when uploading files to a server.**

I set it disabled. it worked.